# size attribute in Struts2 UI Tags

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

Could anyone explain me what does `size` attribute do in struts2 tags ?

Does it limit input at the time user in entering value to respective field ? Or is it for something that happens after submission of form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the page is rendered, [Struts tags](https://struts.apache.org/docs/textfield.html) don't exist anymore, they've become pure HTML at that point.

So it's definitely NOT *for something that happens after submission of form*.

The `size` attribute is the HTML size attribute, it styles a textfield (in a very old way, you should use CSS instead), if you want to limit the inputable chars, you might want to use `maxlength`.

Comment: yes I want to limit the no of character those can be entered in a textfield.

Comment: "if you want to limit the inputable chars, you might want to use maxlength"